# React / Slider Component / Value of the slider is blocked on previous state

Tags: reactjs

I have a slider (almost) with this behaviour:

When I click in the spectrum circle, it updates the slider to 50.

When I click in the colored thumbnail images, it updates to 12.

In both case I use hook function.

But then I can't adjust the slider in both case. It goes back to 12 or 50

Here is my App.js

```
  const [images, UpdateListImages] = useState(RefArray);
  const [currentColor, UpdateCurrentColor] = useState("#fff");
  const sliderInit = [0,11,100];
  const [posSlider, UpdatePosSlider ] = useState(sliderInit);

...

 <ReactSlider
          className="vertical-slider"
          defaultValue={[0,13,100]}
          value={posSlider}
          renderThumb={(props, state) => <div {...props}>{state.valueNow}</div>}
          orientation="vertical"
          invert
          minDistance={1}
          onAfterChange={calculateNewlistFromSlider}
        />
```

[image: screencopy]

**EDIT01**
In the official documentation, the renderThumb props is defined as :

> Provide a custom render function for dynamic thumb content. The
> render function will be passed two arguments, an object with props
> that should be added to your thumb node, and an object with thumb and
> slider state:
>
> (props, state) => <div {...props} />

- props {object} props to be spread into your thumb node
- state.index {number} the index of the thumb
- state.value {number | array} the current value state
- state.valueNow {number} the value of the thumb (i.e. aria-valuenow)

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that in the function slider onAfterChange I called, I needed to delete the hook state.

Simple fix :

```
function calculateNewlistFromSlider(e) {
            
   UpdatePosSlider()
    // rest of the code 
   }
```